# Why so many tables for single entity in EAV model

Tags: magento2, eav

In magento EAV model, I want to know why we need to create so many tables depending upon data type? And, how we going to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EAV is used because it much more scalable than the usual normalised database structure. Developers can add attributes to any entity (product, category, customer, order etc) without modifying the core database structure. When a custom attribute is added, no logic must be added to force Magento to save this attribute because it is all already built into the model; as long as the data is set and the attribute has been created, the model will be saved!

Comment: thank you for clarifying i thought we have to implement our own logic to insert data into respective entity table.Here how we can practically define 'attribute'.Is it like a field value

Comment: ya got the total scenario i have gone through magento customer entity.but let us assume we have added new attribute laptop_id to product entity.whenever we insert data to product it's enough to load default product model ... and use setLaptopId('12345').is my assumption correct

Comment: its cleared thak you .. as i am new user with less reputation i can't vote up ... really its helpfull

Comment: mark it as answer if cant upvote